# RxJS prevent switchMap to send request in first place

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a component which is subscribed to an event that is fired multiple times at the same time. This subscription starts a request to the server to fetch data. What I want to achieve is firing only one single request.

Instead I receive lots of canceled requests until the final request is finished:

[image]

**Updated:**

```
this.someObject.onEvent()
  .pipe(switchMap((filterCriterias) => this.loadData(filterCriterias)))
  .subscribe((res) => {
    this.data = res;
});
```

Is there a way to sort of create a catch basin and only fire last request as in the picture (to not get canceled requests in the first place)?

I'm using RxJs 6.3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do all four requests contain the same data and would it be okay if the first completes while all the others are vanished?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm dealing with a race condition issue and first two requests have no data, only the last has..

Comment: That's why I'm using switchMap but the canceled requests are some what irritating.

Comment: Then you only can only improve your `loadData()` method, to check if it has some valid data and only in that case really send out the http request. Otherwise it should return `empty()`.

Comment: Or your `someObject` has to check for valid data and only in case of valid data emit the event.

Comment: Some more informations about the mapping operators can be found at: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/

Comment: So your http request depend on data emitted by the source event and you only want to send the request when your event emits the right data?

Comment: The not best solution I came up with now is actually to combine more or less all answers: I optimized the `loadData()` function to check for correct request options and using`debounceTime` for a catch basin. But still using `switchMap` which gives still some canceled requests but I can't increase `debounceTime` any more.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you could use `exhaustMap` instead of `switchMap`.

`exhaustMap` will ignore all subsequent emissions until the inner Observable completes. So even if `onEvent()` emits five times only the first one will trigger `this.loadData()`. All other emissions will be ignored until the active `this.loadData()` completes.

```
this.someObject.onEvent()
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => this.loadData())
  )
  .subscribe((res) => ...);
```

Comment: The problem with `exhaustMap` is, that if an emission which has no data that is needed for the request emits earlier, then I get no response from the request.

Comment: Well, I guess you should filter out emissions that aren't supposed to trigger any requests...

Comment: if response is cachable, why not cache it for subsequent requests?

Answer (score 3):

```
this.someObject.onEvent()
  .pipe(debounceTime(300),switchMap(() => this.loadData()))
  .subscribe((res) => {
    this.data = res;
});
```